# Handling complexity of a scheduling and matching

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, scheduling, matching

Is there a way to provide a np-complete proof of this following problem :

> given a set of `N  0-1` vectors (which can be considered as jobs)
>   every job has a number of tasks to be proceeded( example : `v_1=(0,1,1,0)` this job needs tasks 2 and 3). In addition we have an integer `T`. the idea is to partition all vectors in `T` separate
>   `sets A_i, i=1,..,T`.  There are some constraints :

- a job in a `set A_i` if started then should be finished before starting the next one in the same set.
- the cost of each task is 1 but if a there's a task j shared between 2 or more jobs at the same time then the cost is only 1.
- So the objective is to minimize this cost. in other words, **find a partition `A_1,..,A_T` and also a permutation of execution of each job in each `set A_i`  so that to find matches between same tasks.**

This problem is a little bit like multiprocessor scheduling if we didn't have those additional constraint, but i couldn't find a formal proof.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This very much does sound like a homework question. I mean, there's nothing wrong with that as in whole, but you pretty much layed out the issue at hand, but provided no resources or your attempts at solving it. Furthermore, at least I found it somewhat unclear from your description what exactly you want to achieve, in already what could count as a 'too broad' question. So.., I sadly voted to close the question until it is [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51934431/edit) further.

Comment: This is not a homework question. Actually, i tried to take my problem and simplify it in terms of partition and matching problems. I gave a lot of time to this problem, it is a mix of parition and matching that are usually not studied in a same problem.